# Soting lists using Heap? Python

Tags: python, sorting

As we all know Heap are a type of sorting mechanism within the study of computer science. So it occurred to me if we can use Heap to sort data into an almost binary tree type form. Is there a way we can use Heap to sort a list into the very basic ascending or descending order?

I think we can, but I am not sure because Heap are meant to sort data in a particular way.

But What do you guys think? Whats your take on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a heap to sort your values; simply pop elements from the heap until the heap is empty; they'll be returned in sorted order:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def heapsort(iterable):
    h = []
    for value in iterable:
        heappush(h, value)
    return [heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]
```

That's because [`heapq.heappop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop) maintains the heap invariant.

Note that this is not as *efficient* as just directly sorting your list. Moreover, the TimSort algorithm used for the built-in `sorted()` function is *stable*; elements with equal value in the sort are kept in the same order. A `heapsort()` on the other hand is not stable.

Comment: but would that guarantee a for example, descending order?

Comment: @Ali: yes, it would, because popping the smallest element from the heap requires that you keep the heap invariant intact.

Comment: ahh  I see. I didnt know such a function 'heapq.heappop() ' existed

Comment: @Ali: `heapq` is just the Python standard library implementation of a heap. An efficient one at that (C optimisations are included), but it is just the standard CS heap.

Comment: okay this is actually very very interesting. Can you explain what is happening after the item is poped out of the heap.

Comment: @Ali: the last element in the heap array is moved to the front and shifted down to maintain the heap.

Comment: @Ali: you can [study the `heapq` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1cde2bbe841a/Lib/heapq.py).

Comment: @Ali: great answer, just to add if you are looking for the algorithmic way to build and understand Heap Sort, check algorithmic books (like: CLR). Better to see the over-all algorithm without built-in function